# Build React component from string with placeholders

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, react-component

I need to dynamically build a React component based on consistently structured text in an unknown order. How do I replace the placeholder numbers (identified in some consistent way, see below) with corresponding components that consume the placeholder as props?

```
const text = "some (1) arbitrary amount of [2] text";

return (
  <div>
    some
    <Component1 var={1} />
    arbitrary amount of 
    <Component2 var={2} />
    text
   </div>
)
```

The placement and order of [] and () is not consistent, so that:

```
const text = "[2] some arbitrary amount (1) of text";

return (
  <div>
    <Component2 var={2} />
    some arbitrary amount
    <Component1 var={1} />
    of text
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit tricky, to simplify we replace only one placeholder `(1)`:

```
const App = () => {
  return <div>{splitAndRender(text, `(1)`, Component1)}</div>;
};
```

Where `splitAndRender` can be implemented like:

```
const splitAndRender = (text, regex, Component) => {
  const splitByRegex = text.split(regex);
  return splitByRegex.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    const isLastItem = index === splitByRegex.length - 1;
    return [...acc, curr, isLastItem ? null : <Component key={index} />];
  }, []);
};
```

For an unknown number of placeholders, it should be done by resursing the returned array from `splitAndRender`, looking for strings, and calling `splitAndRender` on such strings.

[image: Edit mystifying-thompson-j9e2m]

Comment: Working on implementing this... I don't see how to pass props to Component1? (Maybe I didn't specify this)...

Comment: Call the JSX syntax inside the function, and its not related to the question

Comment: Updated question to reflect. Sorry to move the goalpost.

Comment: You see in the answer how I pass the key prop... Just pass the props in the function, everything you need is included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes possible, you could do something like this

```
  const C1 = () => " C1 ";
  const C2 = () => " C2 ";
  const dynamics = { // the ids of these dynamic components that will be used as placeholders
    1: C1,
    2: C2
  };
  const text = "some (1) arbitrary amount of [2] text";
   // you may want to customize this function to suit your needs
  const isDynamic = src => {
    return (
      (src[0] === "(" && src[src.length - 1] === ")") ||
      ("[" && src[src.length - 1] === "]")
    );
  };
  const components = text.split(" ");

// dont forget to add a key to the mapped components, but i will leave this to you, since i dont have all the requirements about the dynamic components, and whether there might be duplicates
  return (
    <div >
      {components.map(comp => {

        if (isDynamic(comp)) {
          const dynamicCompId = parseInt(
            comp
              .split("")
              .filter(x => !Number.isNaN(+x))
              .join("")
          );
          const Dynamic = dynamics[dynamicCompId];
          return <Dynamic   />;
        }
        return comp;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this method which is straightforward and efficient, and saves from having to do nested / iterative loops as the number of needles becomes larger:

```js
// Function to split string on multiple needles, keeping needles in place
function splitMulti(str, needles) {
  let out = str.valueOf()
  for (var i = 0; i < needles.length; i++) {
    out = out.replace(needles[i], `SPLITDELIN${needles[i]}SPLITDELIN`);
  }
  out = out.split('SPLITDELIN');
  return out;
}


function buildChildren(string){
  // string = "some (1) arbitrary amount of [2] text";

  
  const needles = [
    "(1)",
    "[2]",
  ];

  const childArray = splitMulti(string, needles);

  childArray.forEach((item, index, array) => {
    switch (item) {
      case "(1)":
        array[index] = <Component1 var={1} />
        break;
      case [2]:
        array[index] = <Component2 var={2} />
        break;
    }
  });

  return childArray;
};
```